# Authenticate Dynamics CRM 2016 Rest Webservice from external system

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, dynamics-crm

I'm running into `CORS` issues when trying to call Dynamics WS from an external HTML page.

I looked at how to enable `CORS` on the server and did so by putting the following lines in the `web.config` of the CRM site.

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

This seemed to solve the `CORS` issue but then raised a new error which stated:

> Authentication failed

I used the [REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) tool to generate the javascript code. However, I'm not sure how to authenticate the call.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
var entity = {};
entity.new_name = "John Smith";
entity.new_guid = "KHU464KOU3";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", "http://crmsitedomain.com/api/data/v8.2/new_consumer", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            alert("Created");
        } else {
            alert(this.status); // is returning "0"
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

I do see a "Token Header" and "Impersonate" options in the tool but where do I get the values for those parameters?

Comment: Just coming across this. Did you find an answer? (If you have one, would be great to answer your own question.) While doing my own research, it looks like you need to register your app with Azure Active Directory. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg327838.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I would undo those changes to the CRM site `web.config`, your not really meant to change the application files, it's probably unsupported, and is unlikely to fix your issue.

The MSDN describes how to successfully authenticate 
[Authenticate to Microsoft Dynamics 365 with the Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt595798.aspx).

Its a bit long winded to reproduce here so please check the links.

> With Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) or internet facing deployments
>   When you use the Web API for Dynamics 365 (online) or an on-premises
>   Internet-facing deployment (IFD) you must use OAuth as described in
>   [Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services using OAuth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg327838.aspx).
>
> If you’re creating a single page application (SPA) using JavaScript
>   you can use the adal.js library as described in [Use OAuth with
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing to connect a Single Page Application to
>   Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt595799.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `adal.js`. But can it be done without having to depend on other libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595797.aspx) MSDN page? This is for Web API, not WS, but its nearly the same

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `adal.js`. But can it be done without having to depend on other libraries?